# How to save a detached entity and replace the content of a one to many relationship?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to replace the content of a one to many relationship when I call save() on a detached entity but it only add the new occurrences and does not remove the old ones (I don't want to load the entity from the database).

Is there a setting to clear relationships without loading/attach the entity?

I'm using spring-data-jpa.

Here is my service:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class StuffService {
    @Autowired
    StuffDao stuffDao;

    public void save(StuffDto stuffDto) {
        // The converter maps the properties into the entity, id included
        Stuff stuff= stuffConverter.dtoToBo(stuffDto);
        stuffDao.save(stuff);
    }
}
```

Dtos

```
public class StuffDto {
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "products-empty")
    @Valid
    private List<ProductStuffDto> products;
}

public class ProductStuffDto {
    Integer order;

    String name;
}
```

Entities

```
@Entity
public class Stuff {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "stuff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ProductStuff> products;
}

@Entity
public class ProductStuff {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stuff_id", nullable = false)
    private Stuff stuff;

    Integer order;

    String name;
}
```

Dao

```
public interface StuffDao extends JpaRepository<Stuff, Long> {}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your JPA provider might support change tracking such that it can detect additions to the list without having fetched the list.  What are you using?

Comment: Hello Chris, our JPA provider is Hibernate. I found the solution by the way. See my answer below (and thank you for looking at my question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
I had to add orphan removal.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "stuff", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
```

It's strange because I always though that the Cascade.REMOVE included in Cascade.ALL had the same effect...

Anyway, I can now save an entity in a detached state and replace its relationships.

Thank you all